# quartz how can i change scope of JobExecutionContext & Scheduler to class level?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduling, job-scheduling

in execute internal method i am getting the Object but after its execution is completed Class level variable again become NULL ? Why?

```
public class CampaignJob extends QuartzJobBean {

Scheduler scheduler ;
JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext ;


@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobCtx)
        throws JobExecutionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("ExecuteInternal method is called.....");
    SchedulerContext schedCtx = null;
    // jobCtx.getTrigger().getFinalFireTime().setSeconds(0);

    jobCtx.getTrigger().setStartTime(new Date());

    try {
        schedCtx = jobCtx.getScheduler().getContext();
        ApplicationContext appCtx = (ApplicationContext) schedCtx.get("applicationContext");

        //here i am getting scheduler obj i want ot use in other method
        scheduler = jobCtx.getScheduler();
        jobExecutionContext = jobCtx;
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables are not preserved between individual job executions simply because Quartz creates a new JobDetail (CampaignJob) instance for each job execution.

Please note that the JobExecutionContext instance is always specific to a particular job execution (e.g. it refers to the trigger that executed the job) and therefore it does not make any sense to preserve it between indiviudual job executions.

If you want to preserve any data between individual job executions, you may want to take a look into the Quartz StatefulJob interface that makes Quartz persist changes made to the JobDataMap (accessible through the JobExecutionContext). There are some rules as to what you should/shouln't put into the JobDataMap considering that Quartz uses standard Java Serialization APIs to serialize and deserialize the JobDataJMap contents.

Comment: Actually i want to control my scheduler for UI i.e form Jsp and on click of pause or stop button scheduler should pause/stop. I google alot but cannot find the solution.

Comment: I want to get the schedular bean in my class. How can I get a bean in my controller class using getbean method? This is dynamic web application. any sample syntax will help. Thank you.

Comment: If your application is Spring-based and you are using the org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean, then you can simply have this bean injected into any of your Spring beans. Otherwise, you will have to cache the Scheduler somewhere in the code that constructs it and starts it and expose it through a getter.

Comment: Also, if you are building some sort of a UI for Quartz, you may want to look into existing solutions, e.g. QuartzDesk (www.quartzdesk.com) that I am the original author of.